# Renaming python.exe to python3.exe for co-existence with python2 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to install both python 2.7 and python 3.5 on my Windows 10 PC. Both python executables use the same name `python.exe`.

Is it a good idea to change `python.exe` to `python3.exe` as a quick fix for co-existence? Are there any side-effects or other things that I need to be aware?

Comment: Why are you installing both?  https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Comment: I have a variant on this problem - I have both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of python (needed by different programs, for example my 64 bit Z3 can only run under 64 bit python). I would like to have both pythons on my path with different names for the exe's obviously. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to rename anything for co-existence of different versions of Python.

The different versions of python are installed on different folders automatically.

When use the command prompt you can use the commands `py2` or `py3` to refer to the different versions of python. The next works too:

```
C:\Users\user1>py -2
```

and

```
C:\Users\user1>py -3
```

This also works with `pip2` and `pip3` for install new packages.

For more details, you can read this article: [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#python-launcher-for-windows).

Comment: user16891328: If you have both installed, you can also add a `#!/usr/bin/env python2` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` comment as the first line of your scripts and use `py scriptname.py` to have the correct interpreter executed.

Comment: @martineau This is a Windows question

Comment: @cricket_007: I know that. `py` makes the shebang work on Windows, too.

Comment: @martineau I meant `#!/usr/bin/env`

Comment: @cricket_007: I understood what you meant. See [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#shebang-lines) of the documentation where it says the the `py` launcher makes the same thing work on Windows.

Comment: And if you associate the `.py` extension with the `py` launcher, then you can just run `scriptname.py` directly without prefixing with `py`; it requires the extension (so Windows can figure out the file type association), but otherwise operates like a shebanged script with the executable bit set on *NIX.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, and if you add .PY to the `PATHEXT` environment variable, you can just run `scriptname` -- unless the file security denies execute access. The latter is only checked by `CreateProcess`, not `ShellExecuteEx`, but cmd.exe (not powershell.exe) first tries `CreateProcess` and won't try `ShellExecuteEx` if the former fails with access denied.

Comment: Note that the core CPython developers don't actively support using py.exe directly as the primary way to run Python. It's still recommended to run `python`. However, they refuse to create symlinks in the directory (e.g. `python3` and `python3.5`) like what is commonly used on Unix systems (you can make your own using cmd's `mklink`). They should integrate the features of py.exe into the core python.exe -- i.e. shebang processing and the `-X[.Y[-32]]` option to locate another Python installation via the registry.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run `python3` instead of `python` if that's not obvious. This is definitely, as you described, a "quick fix"

My suggested fix is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and pass in the Python executable you would like to use as so:

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 /my/virtualenv/>`

Comment: You can change that to wherever your Python 3.5 exe is found.